# Mean-variance framework with endogenous correlations

Tags: correlation, mean-variance

In most mean-variance frameworks I have seen, once we clear markets in the model, it determines asset prices (and returns). However, all of these frameworks assume that the correlation matrix of the underlying assets is given exogenously. Is there any mean-variance type model with an endogenous correlation matrix? I.e. correlations that depend on the demand of each asset of each investor ?

Comment: There are a few reasons for the scarcity of such papers. First, the standard MV model is one period so dividend correlations determine return correlations. Second, with MV there are no wealth effects as in for example this paper: https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.2015.2413.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, [A Rational Theory of Mutual Funds' Attention Allocation](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.3982/ECTA11412) has one such example of this, where excess returns are an endogenous response to attention allocation. One of my favorite papers of all time!